# Sorted key returning NoneType comparison TypeError

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list made up of objects and lists of (the same type of) objects during a unittest setup, but I'm getting a `TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to NoneType`.

I know it's incredibly simple, but what am I missing!?

```
objs = [myobject, myobject]
more_objs = [[myobject, myobject], [myobject, myobject]]

def sort_all_objs(data):
    """
    Sort mixed list by the dates.
    """
    if isinstance(data, list):
        sort_all_objs(data[0])
    else:
        date = getattr(data.calculation, 'duedate')
        if date:
            return date
        raise AttributeError("List doesn't have objects with a duedate attribute: {0}".format(data.calculation))


all_objs = objs + more_objs 
all_objs = sorted(self.all_objs, key=sort_all_objs)
```

Comment: Dp you mean `sort_all_objs` where you have `sort_all_payments`, and `more_objs` where you have `other_objs`?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor well spotted. I've edited vars & defs to make simpler - didn't quite check over it enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sort_all_objs` function:

```
if isinstance(data, list): 
    sort_all_objs(data[0]) # recursively call the function
    # no return here
else:
    # else branch returns a date object
```

The function itself has no return value given so `None` is returned for sublists.

You might instead want:

```
    return sort_all_objs(data[0])
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I do believe you're right. I don't do a lot of recursive functionality so I thought it'd just run through again and return the value given from `data[0]`